# Spark - Folder with same name as text file automatically created after RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, rdd

I placed a text file named Linecount2.txt in hdfs and built a simple rdd to count the number of lines using spark.

```
val lines = sc.textFile("user/root/hdpcd/Linecount2.txt")
lines.count()
```

This works.

But when I tried using the same text file with the aforementioned path, I receive the error:

```
 "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist:"
```

When I looked into that path, I could see a folder was created 'Linecount.txt'.Hence the path for the file is now

```
("user/root/hdpcd/Linecount2.txt/Linecount2.txt")
```

Then, after defining the path I was able to run it successfully.

The third time I tried this, I got the same error because input path doesn't exist.

When I went through the path,

[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Please add the code which places the file in the folder. You haven't shown us the code which causes your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between putting an HDFS file at `user/root/hdpcd/Linecount2.txt` compared to `/user/root/hdpcd/Linecount2.txt`, (or, more simply `hdpcd/Linecount2.txt`, when you already are the root user)

The leading slash is very important if you want to place a file in an absolute directory other than your current user account, otherwise, that's the default.

You've not given your hdfs put command, but the issue here is simply the difference between the absolute and relative paths. And it's not Spark specifically that's the issue

Also, `hdfs put` will say that a file already exists if you try to place it in the same location, so the fact you were able to upload twice should be an indication that your path was incorrect